# C# - InvalidCastException when reading from HttpSessionState

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very simple method that looks like this:

```
    public void DoSmth(int y)
    {
        XXXXX x = (XXXXX)Session["key"];
        x.DoSmthElse(y);
    }
```

But I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type Z.YYYYY to type Z.XXXXX
   at XYZ.DoSmth(Int32 y)
```

Exception itself makes sense, but why possibly does it occur? What can I do to prevent it? Why does Session["key"] have type there?

Comment: What did you set `Session["key"]` to originally?  The type of the original set value will be preserved

Comment: Whatever you put in `Session["key"]` has a type - apparently `Z.YYYYY` and this type cannot be cast to `Z.XXXXX`.  For instance, if you put a `string` in the collection, you can't cast it to `double`.  What did you put in and what are you trying to cast it to?

Comment: The error message asserts that an implicit conversion will not work. You will have to explicitly convert `Session["Key"]` to type (Z.YYYYY). `DoSmthElse(int)` isn't handling the conversion correctly. Expose `DoSmthElse()` for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Exception itself makes sense, but why possibly does it occur?

- Because Session["key"] type is not XXXXX
  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing)

What can I do to prevent it?

- You can check if Session["key"] contains the right type like this

  ```
  if (Session["key"] is XXXXX x)
  {
     x.DoSmthElse(y);
  }
  ```

Why does Session["key"] have type there?

- each variable have a type